# преобразовать дату создания modx

Tags: php

как в php преобразовать в дату такое значение 1495781048

Comment: Похоже на [UNIX timestamp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F), это и есть дата в секундах с начала 1970 года. Ищите функцию, которая принимает такое значение.

Comment: `echo date('r', 1495781048);`

Comment: выполняю вот так в mysql SELECT date_format(`date_field`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as `date_field` FROM `table`

выдает NULL

Comment: разобрался

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`createdon`), '%Y-%m-%d') as `createdon` FROM `modx_users`